# Select last descendent of a particular tag

Tags: jquery

I have a table, which is split up as follows:

```
<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- unknown number of rows -->
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to select the last `<tr>` in this table.  I've tried `$('#myTable > td:last')` but that doesn't seem to work.  when I do `console.log($('#myTable > tr:last').html())`, I get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea with `$('#myTable > tr:last')`, but tables actually also include a `<tbody>` tag...if you don't put one in yourself, then the browser puts it in for you. So you need to use this instead:

```
$('#myTable tr:last')
```

Don't use the `>` selector, because that requires that the element following it has to be a *direct* child of the preceding element.

Also, `$('#myTable > td:last')` is definitely incorrect because a `<td>` element is never a direct child of a `<table>` element - it's inside a `<tr>`, which in turn is inside a `<tbody>` or `<thead>`.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` selects a direct child element from the parent, so it's not selecting your `td` which is nested two levels from `#myTable`

Try this for your selector instead:

```
$('#myTable tr:last-child td')
```

Or if you want the last `td` of the last `tr`

```
$('#myTable tr:last-child td:last-child')
```